# Can I get the job variable from the job_id？

Tags: qiskit, programming, ibm-q-experience

Suppose I run the following code：

`job = execute(qc, backend = backend, shots = 1024, optimization_level = 0)`

Then the job takes a long time to run. We know that job_id (from `job.job_id()`) is a unique identifier for a job. Can I just save job_id and then turn it off and restore the job variable with job_id the next day?

Or what information can I save that will allow me to get the `job.result()` after I drop the line?

The motivation for this problem is that I don't want to increase the workload due to network reasons when I am waiting for many tasks to run. It will be much easier to handle data when there is `job.result()`. Otherwise, I can only go to `https://quantum-computing.ibm.com/` to download the result data, and the data format is not easy to use.

thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it you're running the jobs on an IBMQ backend and not one of the local simulators.
If so, just keep track of `job_id`, then use the [retrieve_job](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.providers.ibmq.IBMQBackend.retrieve_job.html) function to retrieve the job at a later point in time and get its result.

Answer (score 1):

In order to fully recover your `Job` object from IBMQ, you need two things:

- the backend name
- the job id

Once you sent your job, you can save those like this:

```
job_id = job.job_id()
backend_name = job.backend().name()
```

Later, when the job is done, you can recover the `Job` object like this:

```
provider = IBMQ.load_account()
job = provider.get_backend(backend_name).retrieve_job(job_id)
```